# как правильно вызвать функцию отдельно для каждой новой кнопки

Tags: javascript

почему вот такой код работает:

```
button.onclick = function() {
  block.classList.toggle('active');

  if (this.innerHTML === 'скрыть') {
    this.innerHTML = 'подробнее';
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'скрыть';
  }
}
```

а вот такой уже нет :

```
function innerButton() {
  if (this.innerHTML === 'скрыть') {
    this.innerHTML = 'подробнее';
  } else {
    this.innerHTML = 'скрыть';
  }
}

button.onclick = function() {
  block.classList.toggle('active');
  innerButton();
}
```

что я делаю не так и как сделать чтобы он заработал?

у меня много кнопок на странице и я хочу вынести функцию по смене названия на них отдельно

Comment: `innerButton();` -> `innerButton.apply(this);`, ето как вариант кроме предложеного в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

так пробните

```
function innerButton(element) {
     if ( element.innerHTML === 'скрыть' ) {
         element.innerHTML = 'подробнее';
     }
     else {
         element.innerHTML = 'скрыть';
     }
 }


button.onclick = function(){ 

    block.classList.toggle('active');

    innerButton(this);
}
```

скорее всего `this` внутри `innerButton` это `innerButton`

Comment: так тоже не работает не работает

Comment: обнорвил ответ а

Comment: ты гений =) блин это круто =) объясни пожалуйста как это работает внутри?

Comment: загули про this в js